# Close hamburger menu on click

Tags: javascript, menu, onclick

I'm looking for a way to make this hamburger menu close after the user clicks the link/makes selection. I've checked out several options on how to do it, but with no luck. I understand I need a missing piece of JS.

The rest of the code (html&css) can be found here (https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/oNGzoYd). Stackoverflow is prohibiting me from posting all of the code (says it's mostly code).

```js
function menuOnClick() {
  document.getElementById("menu-bar").classList.toggle("change");
  document.getElementById("nav").classList.toggle("change");
  document.getElementById("menu-bg").classList.toggle("change-bg");
}
```

Comment: "*The rest of the code (html&css) can be found here*" - please incorporate the minimal required ("*[mcve] code*") into the question; don't expect us to look around the internet to third-party sites in order to help you.

Comment: Yeah I know, however as stated it didn't let me through. I added comments in the code, some additional text as well as googled for answers to to avail. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to pass in the onclick function to the nav.

This should do the trick:

```
<div id="menu">
  <div id="menu-bar" onclick="menuOnClick()">
    <div id="bar1" class="bar"></div>
    <div id="bar2" class="bar"></div>
    <div id="bar3" class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <nav class="nav" id="nav" onclick="menuOnClick()">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav> 
</div>

<div class="menu-bg" id="menu-bg"></div>
```

Comment: Or simply put it in the `<nav>` selection once, instead of 4 times in each `<li>`

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, just call the same `menuOnClick()` function on every `<li>` item on the list.

```html
      <li onclick="menuOnClick()"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li onclick="menuOnClick()"><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li onclick="menuOnClick()"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li onclick="menuOnClick()"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
```